# Не парсится Nlohmann JSON

Tags: c++, json

Все, кто знаком с Nlohmann JSON буду рад помощи.

Пытаюсь запустить этот код, который парсит json и описан в документации к библиотеке(https://github.com/nlohmann/json#examples):

```
#include "errors.h"
#include "argparser.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>
#include <fstream>

#include <QDebug>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QCommandLineParser>
#include <QScopedPointer>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonArray>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDir>

#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

using namespace std;
using json = nlohmann::json;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {   
    ifstream ifs("/home/user/.students-rating/groups/пми-21бо.json");
    json j ;
    ifs >> j;

    return 0;
}
```

Вот этот json:

```
{
    "students": [
        {
            "name": "Иванов Иван",
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "Плюшкин Василий",
            "id": 2
        },
    ]
}
```

Но получаю ошибку :[image: ошибка]

Путь к файлу несколько раз перепроверил, прописан верно.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: 1) точно путь правильный, а то там точка. 2) ваш сам джсон невалидный, т.к. там лишняя запятая в конце массива 3) не помню что там в линупсе, но проверьте кодировку исходников, возможно киррилические пути могут работать неверно 4) используйте обработку исключений, анализ errno и вот это всё, оно даст ответ о том что произошло, банально посмотреть стэк вызовов и уже будет понятнее, что именно упало. P.S. вывод what() говорит, что мой п.2. верный, удалите запятую и будет вам счастье) для проверки джсонин используйте что-то типа https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Да, действительно json был не валиден. Спасибо за ответ